# How to join lines from output in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a command which outputs in this format:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
I
J
```

etc
I want the output to be in this format

```
A B C D E F G I J
```

I tried using `./script | tr "\n" "  "` but all it does is remove `n` from the output
How do I get all the output in one line.

> Edit: I accidentally put in grep while asking the question. I removed
> it. My original question still stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `grep` is superfluous.

This should work:

```
./script | tr '\n' ' '
```

It did for me with a command `al` that lists its arguments one per line:

```
$ al A B C D E F G H I J
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
$ al A B C D E F G H I J | tr '\n' ' '
A B C D E F G H I J $
```

Comment: `tr "\n" " "` should work. The OP's original command wasn't even invoking `tr`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, I've removed the extra comment.  `bash` at least seems to convert `\n` inside double quotes into an actual newline. (I'm pretty sure that Bourne shell never did that.) Indeed, `bash` seems to do that inside single quotes (which strikes me as very dubious; the contents of single quotes are supposed to be inviolate, from one single quote to the next.  If that changes, there's no way to be sure that you get what (die-hard Bourne-shell programmers) expect.

Comment: No, but the `tr` command translates the backslash-n sequence into a newline.

Comment: For ls -al the tr '\n' ' ' works. I am using redis command which lists all the attributes vertically. But when I use |  tr '\n' ' ' it outputs a blank line

Comment: Does `redis` generate CRLF line endings?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it has carriage returns. So, I changed it to | tr '\n\r' ' ' and it works now

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: using double quotes invokes shell interpolation, if you want a new-line (in the shell) use `$'\n'`.  `tr(1)` also translates special characters, but you need single quotes to protect them from the shell. `echo '\n'` gives `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

As Jonathan Leffler points out, you don't want the `grep`.  The command you're using:

```
./script | grep tr "\n" " "
```

doesn't even invoke the `tr` command; it *should* search for the pattern `"tr"` in files named `"\n"` and `" "`. Since that's not the output you reported, I suspect you've mistyped the command you're using.

You can do this:

```
./script | tr '\n' ' '
```

but (a) it joins all its input into a single line, and (b) it doesn't append a newline to the end of the line. Typically that means your shell prompt will be printed at the end of the line of output.

If you want everything on one line, you can do this:

```
./script | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo ''
```

Or, if you want the output wrapped to a reasonable width:

```
./script | fmt
```

The `fmt` command has a number of options to control things like the maximum line length; read its documentation (`man fmt` or `info fmt`) for details.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use other programs, why not use Bash to do the job? (`--` added in edit)

```
line=$(./script.sh) 
set -- $line
echo "$*"
```

The `set` sets command-line options, and one of the (by default) seperators is a "\n".  EDIT: This will overwrite any existing command-line arguments, but good coding practice would suggest that you reassigned these to named variables early in the script.

When we use `"$*"` (note the quotes) it joins them alll together again using the *first character* of `IFS` as the glue.  By default that is a space.

`tr` is an unnecessary child process.

By the way, there is a command called `script`, so be careful of using that name.

Comment: The `set` is superfluous as well, and could overwrite script parameters. `echo "${line[*]}"` should work just as well.

Comment: wordsplit + pathname expansion + possible conflicts with `set` options without `--` most likely. Pretty good collection of all the issues with this over [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments)

Comment: You got me.  I usually includde the `--` but I omitted them this time.  `echo "${line[*]}"` would only work if `line` was an array.  As it stands it is not, but it is easy to do with and extra set of parens: `line=($(./script.sh))`.  I like that one.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the `echo` command will automatically remove the newline chars when its argument is given *unquoted*:

```
tmp=$(./script.sh)
echo $tmp
```

results in

```
A B C D E F G H I J
```

whereas

```
tmp=$(./script.sh)
echo "$tmp"
```

results in

```
A 
B 
C 
D 
E 
F 
G 
H 
I 
J
```

If needed, you can re-assign the output of the `echo` command to another variable:

```
tmp=$(./script.sh)
tmp2=$(echo $tmp)
```

The `$tmp2` variable will then contain no newlines.