# How to wrap output lines in quotes in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

Essentially I want the inverse operation performed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11338191/24874).

I'm running a search, looking for files that have Windows line endings (`\r\n`) as I want to [remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521339/24874).

```sh
$ grep -URl ^M .
```

Some of the returned files have spaces in their names:

```
./file name 1.txt
./file name 2.txt
```

In order to pass this on to another tool via `xargs`, I need to quote the lines. How can I transform to this output instead:

```
"./file name 1.txt"
"./file name 2.txt"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [xargs input involving spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952744/xargs-input-involving-spaces)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BSD `grep` provides a `--null` option to print names followed by a null byte (instead of a newline).

GNU `grep` provides a `-Z` or `--null` option with the same semantics.

Both BSD and GNU `xargs` take a `-0` option to indicate that file names are separated by null bytes.

Hence:

```
grep -URl --null ^M . | xargs -0 ...
```

Comment: This works nicely in this specific case as it avoids an intermediary quoted representation. I'm still curious as to how you'd produce such a quoted form though.

Comment: Note that `xargs` won't pay attention to quotes in the names, and will split at white space unless you use `-0`.  If you're seeking to use the output in a `for file in $(grep -URl ...)` type construct, you have to work hard.  Life was much easier when spaces in file names were eschewed as errors that were fixed by renaming the files (say, back in the 80s).  You'd probably want to use single quotes rather than double quotes as otherwise you might run into problems with notations such as `$(...)` embedded in a file name.  Newlines in file names are a bit problematic too.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the space problem I'd use new line character as separator for xargs with the -d option:

```
xargs -d '\n' ...
```

So my solution would be:

```
grep -URl ^M . | xargs -d '\n' rm
```